# How to convert a xml which has been converted by SimpleXMLElement and xpath back to String in php?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

i converted this string into an array with SimpleXMLElement and xpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
   <epos-print xmlns="http://www.epson-pos.com/schemas/2014/05/epos-print"><pulse/>
    <text align="center" ul="0" em="0" dw="1" dh="1" smooth="1" lang="de">Shoppingqueen</text>
    <feed/>
    <text align="center" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="1" lang="de">Text me</text>
    <feed/>
    <text align="center" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="1" lang="de">Hello People</text>
    <feed/>
    <text align="left" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Hello world</text>
    <feed line="2"/>
    <text align="center" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Some text</text>
    <feed line="2"/>
    <text align="left" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Chocolate                         20,00 EUR A</text>
    <feed/>
    <text align="left" ul="1" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Apples                      15,00 EUR A</text>
    <feed/>
    <text align="left" ul="0" em="1" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Onion                   35,00 EUR  </text>
    <feed line="2"/>
    <text align="left" ul="0" em="0" dw="0" dh="0" smooth="0" lang="de">Cash                     35,00 EUR  </text>
    <cut/>
   </epos-print>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Thats how converted it into an array of objects.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlText);

$texts = $xml->xpath("epos-print/text");
```

After the conversion i changed some values within the nodes. 
I changed chocolate to vanilla as example.
Now i need it to convert back to the same string (of course with the changed node values) in order to save it in database.
How can i do it?
According to the php api the toString is not working and asXML() did not work, i got the error-message that asXML cant be used on array.

Please help.

Comment: How did you call the `toString()` or `asXML()` methods? Show that code.

Comment: i used asXML() like this : $texts->asXML()

Comment: I see, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `asXML()` on the original object:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlText);

$texts = $xml->xpath("epos-print/text");

// Change chocolate to vanilla

$new_xml = $xml->asXML();
```

---

Per the docs or the [`xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method:

> Returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects or FALSE in case of an error.

So the return of xpath is an array of simplexml objects which are assigned by reference by default.